Vite App is not serving data from public folder in Github Pages
I recently deployed a Vite + React App onto GitHub Pages, which worked as expected on my local host. But on Pages, it does not serve assets that are placed in the public folder.
I've changed my base in the config, and adjusted the routes to match the base of the server. The project does not use react-router, as it only consists of one page. And I also am not including "public" in the path. I tried, but the app stopped working altogether.
